# How do I get the desktop path in AppxManifest

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge, appx, appxmanifest

I'm trying to migrate my app to the UWP-Platform using the Desktop Bridge.

In this blog post it is explained how to migrate the desktop shortcut: 
https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/03/10/desktop-bridge-smooth-user-transition-data-migration/

In short, the manifest should contain something like this:

```xml
<rescap3:Extension Category="windows.desktopAppMigration">
    <rescap3:DesktopAppMigration>
        <rescap3:DesktopApp AumId="[your_app_aumid]" />
        <rescap3:DesktopApp ShortcutPath="%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\[my_app].lnk" />
    </rescap3:DesktopAppMigration>
</rescap3:Extension>
```

However a users desktop is not always located at `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop`. A clean install of Windows 10 will put the Desktop inside of OneDrive `%USERPROFILE%\OneDrive\Desktop` (depending on settings).

Is there a better way to get the desktop folder inside an AppxManifest?

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define multiple *ShortcutPath*s in the AppXManifest.

At deployment time, the OS will look for the lnk file and if it doesn't find it, it moves to the next *ShortcutPath* in order until it finds it (if it exists at all).

Does that work for your scenario?

Comment: This works for me, any shortcuts to the desktop version that remain, will be deleted by my desktop app uninstaller.